# Jep:error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DLLs\\jep.pyd'

Tags: python-2.7, jepp

During jep build I get the following error:

[image]

I get this error when I run the below code

```
python setup.py install
```

How to overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some resarch i've found the answer.

You just have to add a folder "DLLs" to your Jep source directory. This will automatically add the jep.dll to the DLLs folder.

This worked for me!!